# incompatible types: void cannot be converted to int

Tags: java, class, void

I'm extremely new when to comes to Java and programming in general. I am trying to create a simple program where you guess my age and if you are right it will say "correct" and if you are wrong it will say "wrong".

This is my code:

```
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner; // This will import just the Scanner class.

public class GuessAge {
    public static int main(int[] args) {
       System.out.println("\nWhat is David's Age?");
       Scanner userInputScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
       int age = userInputScanner.nextLine();



        int validInput = 20;
        if (validInput == 20) {
            return System.out.println("Correct!!");
        }
        else {
            return System.out.println("Wrong....");
        }
    }
}
```

I get the error "incompatible types: void cannot be converted to int" but I have no void class in the code? I know my code is probably awful but if you guys could point me in the right direction that would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your program does not have to return an `int` in `public static int main`. Instead you can have it as `void` (meaning don't return anything). You should simply just print your statements and don't `return` them. Also the `int[]` should be `String[]` and `Scanner` should check for `nextInt()` as pointed out in comments!

```
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner; // This will import just the Scanner class.

public class GuessAge {
public static void main(String[] args) {
   System.out.println("\nWhat is David's Age?");
   Scanner userInputScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
   int age = userInputScanner.nextInt();



    int validInput = 20;

    // typo in your code - compare to age
    if (validInput == age) {
        System.out.println("Correct!!");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Wrong....");
    }
}

}
```

Comment: `int age = userInputScanner.nextLine();` looks a bit strange too.

Comment: Your right - the code needs a better refactor. Two seconds

Comment: nextInt() would be better

Comment: Updated answer with changes!

Comment: Thank you Germaine and everyone else! Very helpful. I got it working! Awesome.

Answer (score 4):

You are trying to return `System.out.println()` which is of type `void`. Remove the `return` statements from before `System.out.println()`, and they will still print. Note that you do not need to specify a return value in the `main` method.

Comment: Also, in your if statement, you are comparing validInput to 20, which is true since you initialized it to 20.  You want to compare age to 20.

Comment: @not_a_bot added your fix to my answer - good call!

Comment: Thank you! I took out the return statements and switched the validinput in the if statement but I am still getting one last error saying string cannot be converted to int and then cmd prompt says shows this line

    int age = userInputScanner.nextline();

Comment: @javanoob look at my full answer

Answer (score 0):

In your method declaration, you have `public static int main(int[] args)`

The word after the `static` keyword is a return type, and in this case your declaration is requiring the main method to return an `int`. To solve this, main should have a void return type, as you're only printing within main and not returning type int.

Comment: Another explanation 

println() is an fuction so neither int, or String type.